# Inner classes as spring-data-repositories

Tags: spring-data

It seems that spring-data only constructs repositories for interfaces that are defined at the top level. For example

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

works great but if i embed it into a class for example

```
public class Repositories {
    public static interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

    }
}
```

i cannot find any documentation on such a restriction. So my question is: Is it possible to define spring-data-repositories as inner-classes?

Comment: Did you define this repository in a context file or is it scanned?

Comment: it is scanned: <jpa:repositories base-package="somepackage">

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should set the [considerNestedRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) boolean to true.

Comment: thanks. for all those who wonder. this option exists since version 1.5.0.RELEASE