# Inner CrudRepository interface in Main doesn't works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was doing some tests with `spring-data-jpa` so to don't make a new file to do the Repository Interface I've put it in the Main as next:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}


@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(BRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        log.info("Insert a");
        repository.save(new EntityA("TestA"));

        log.info("Find a " + repository.findOne(1));

    };
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public static class EntityA{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    //Getters, setters && constructors

}

public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityA, Integer> {

}

}
```

Then I've tested it with the `@Bean` `CommandLineRunner`to see the output but I got an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'demo' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [hello.Application$BRepository] found for dependency [hello.Application$BRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.Application$BRepository] found for dependency [hello.Application$BRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:27) [classes/:na]
```

Finally to ensure I've not done some wrong I've tested it doing the Interface repository in a new file and it works.

- Someone knows why doesn't works the repository with a inner interface?
- Is this an issue or doesn't works for some reason? (Or maybe I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: put the `@Repository` annotation from `org.springframework.stereotype` package on your `BRepository` interface.

Comment: It doesn't work with `@Repository`... same Exception.

Comment: did you try to annotate your `Application` class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations?

Comment: It is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which is composed by `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan`, `@SpringBootConfiguration`,.. And I've tried with `@EnableJpaRepositories` but doesn't works either...

Comment: sure, you're right.

Comment: can you show your test code?

Comment: It's not a unit test, just a simple `insert` and `findOne`. You can see it in the `CommandLineRunner demo(BRepository repository)` method

Comment: What's the point of making it a nested class anyway? It really should be a top-level interface, and entities can't be nested classes either, by specification. Even if it's a bug/limitation, I don't think it deserves being fixed: the right thing is to define it as a top-level interface.

Comment: I just did tests and I did not understand why this way did not work. Sure you are right and this limitation (if it is) doesn't deserve being fixed.

Comment: I would assume the reason that this doesn't work is because the interface declaration itself is not visible to Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring doesn't see nested repositories, to make it do see, use `@EnableJpaRepositories` (although it's already included in `@SpringBootApplication`) and set the [considerNestedRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) boolean to true.

Source post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24485491/2816631